# return line of strings between two strings in a ruby variable

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to extract a line of strings but am having difficulties using the correct RegEx. Any help would be appreciated.

String to extract: KSEA 122053Z 21008KT 10SM FEW020 SCT250 17/08 A3044 RMK AO2 SLP313 T01720083 50005

For Some reason StackOverflow wont let me cut and paste the XML data here since it includes "<>" characters. Basically I am trying to extract data between  "raw_text"  ... "/raw_text" from a xml that will always be formatted like the following: http://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&hoursBeforeNow=3&mostRecent=true&stationString=PHNL%20KSEA

However, the Station name, in this case "KSEA" will not always be the same. It will change based on user input into a search variable.

Thanks In advance

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Can you paste a better sample data and your expected output? What is the pattern you want to match?

Comment: More specifically, we can't give you a good answer with only one example input and one example output. For example, I could say that `str[8...90]` does the job, but that probably won't be a general solution to your problem.

Comment: There's no point in extracting a string literal (since you already know what it is), but can easily determine if it's present. For that, if `str = "19190453KSEA...5METAR136.0"`and `substr = "KSEA 122053Z...50005"`, it's just `str.include?(substr)`.

Comment: Thanks guys. Actually what I am trying to do is parse an XML. I have already. The XML Data looks like this from the Aviation.gov weather service: link : http://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&hoursBeforeNow=3&mostRecent=true&stationString=PHNL%20KSEA

Comment: I never parse XML, but everyone here who does seems to recommend [Nokogiri](https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri). There are some tutorials [here](http://www.nokogiri.org).

Answer (score 0):

if I can assume that every strings that you want starts with KSEA, then the answer would be:

```
.*(KSEA.*?)KSEA.*
```

using `?` would let `.*` match as less as possible.